# check current network speed linux

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to get current network speed like shown in System Monitor on GNOME.
I need this to be in terminal and if possible no installations needed (on most of distros this tool i need should be installed by default with the system).

So i don't want to ping anything or stuff like that, I just want to check speed in simplest way possible without adding new tools.

I hope there is a tool that will show information in terminal like System Monitor -> Resources -> Network history.

EDIT:
if there is a workaround in Java to get this information without using linux commands this would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know what tools you already have installed on your system. I'd recommend either `bmon`, `ifstat`, or `ifstat -S` if you want the information printed on the same time.

The above should be in your distro's central repository (aptitude, yum etc) so should be easy to install if they're not aready there.

Comment: was looking to avoid using tools i need to install but ok ifstat -S will work because there is no workaround currently and this one has the way of giving me less info than other tools

Answer (score -1):

The Java class InetAddress has an isReachable() method. You could try this:

```
public long getSpeed() {
    InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean reachable = inet.isReachable(5000);
    if (reachable) {
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return end - start;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This will 'sort of' do a ping, but how the isReachable() method is implemented is not really specified. Doing an actual ping command from Java itself is not supported though, so this is (I think) the best you can do.

Comment: not the solution i was looking for but thx for example i may need this later on